# preg_match in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

I have a JSON array:

```
[{"name":"foo bar"},{"name":"john doe"}]
```

Now, I want to make a function: when I'm typing in an input field "foo", "foo bar" has to appear. But if I type "bar", "foo bar" has to appear also.

So how can I check if a text contains the input?

(I hope my question is clear enough)

Comment: Why would you use a regex for a plain "string x is in string y" check?

Comment: So, you want to check if a certain string is in another string? [`string.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: What a link! Thanks @MarceloDiniz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this simple task you don't really need regular expressions. Here is how to find out whether a string contains a substring:

```
var string = 'foo bar';
string.indexOf('foo') != -1 // true
string.indexOf('bar') != -1 // true
string.indexOf('baz') != -1 // false
```

If you wanted to make the search a bit more user-friendly, you could make it case-insensitive:

```
function matches(string, substring) {
   return string.toLowerCase().indexOf(substring.toLowerCase()) != -1
}

matches('Foo Bar', 'BAR'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking specifically for regular expressions to achieve this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

If any other function is fine:

```
var str = "Check for substring";
if (str.indexOf("sub") >= 0)
{
    alert("contains");
}
else
{
    alert("Does not contain");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a whole word match, your regular expression should be `\bfoo\b`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get suggestions for the item "John doe", as soon as the User types a "J", then, you'd better look into [Trie's (yes, Trie, not Tree!)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and implement it (find a lib) or you could settle with full word queries;
you'd first need to split your words by whitespace and collect each word;

```
var jsonArray=[{"name":"foo bar"},{"name":"john doe"}];
var wordLookup={};
var item,split;
for (var i=0,e=jsonArray.length;i<e;++i){
    item=jsonArray[i];
    split=item.split(" ");
    for (var u=0;u<split.length;++u){
        if (typeof wordLookup[ split[0] ]==="undefined"){
            wordLookup[ split[0] ]=[];
        }
        wordLookup[ split[0] ].push(i);

    }
}
```

then you would have your input field

```
<input type="text" id="suggestion" name="suggestion"/>
```

and would bind an event to it that searches for a matched word on keydown

```
document.getElementById("suggestion").addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    var list="",val,vs,ve;
    for (vs=0,ve=this.value.length;vs<ve;++vs){
        if (vs===0){val="";}
        val+=this.value.charAt(vs);
        if ( wordLookup[val] ){
            for (var i=0;e=wordLookup[val].length;i<e;++i){
                list+="- "+jsonArray[ wordLookup[val][i] ].name;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("possible matches; "+list);
});
```

'sadly', its not possible to regexp the key of an object(hash/map). I would suggest iterating threw all expanded possibilities a,ab,abc,abcd.., like the code above demonstrates.

of course, instead of alerting the user what he could select, showing him those within a dropdown, that he could select is the way to go. But my code should direct you into the right direction on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For an easier approach, if this is enough for your needs, you can try this path:

```
var myArray = [{"name":"foo bar"},{"name":"john doe"}];

function autoFill(input, charCode, minLength)
{
    if (typeof(minLength) == 'undefined') { minLength = 3; }

    var newInsertedValue = input.value + String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (newInsertedValue.length >= minLength)
    {
        for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
        {
            var valueToFill = myArray[i].name.toString();
            if (valueToFill.match(newInsertedValue))
            {
                return valueToFill;
            }
        }
    }

    return newInsertedValue;
}
```

And then modify your input tag like this:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="this.value=autoFill(this, event.charCode); return false" />
```

The function will auto fill when the user will type at least 3 chars (for example by typing `foo`), if you want it to start auto filling starting from a different string chars (for example by typing `fo` or `ba`) you can do it by adding a third param like

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="this.value=autoFill(this, event.charCode, 2); return false" />
```